# Asymptotic analysis for multiple variables?

Tags: computer-science, asymptotics

How is asymptotic analysis (big o, little o, big theta, big theta etc.) defined for functions with multiple variables?

I know that the Wikipedia article has a section on it, but it uses a lot of mathematical notation which I am unfamiliar with it. I also found the following paper: http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~rhowell/asymptotic.pdf However the paper is very long and provides a complete analysis of asymptotic analysis rather than just giving a definition. Again the frequent usage of mathematical notation made it very hard to understand.

Could someone provide a definition of asymptotic analysis *without* the complex mathematical notation?

Comment: Could you gave more context for what you're interested in (i.e. what problem you're trying to solve using asymptotic analysis for multiple variables) or perhaps a more detailed description about what notation or concepts you find confusing?